# In Emacs on my Mac, how can `Compile Command` see PATH set in ~/.bashrc?

Tags: macos, bash, emacs

In Emacs v23.4.1 on my Mac OSX Mavericks, how can `Meta-x compile` see `$PATH` for bash as set in my ~/.bashrc?  Right now, `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` whereas in a normal shell it is `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools`

Surprisingly, passing `bash -c "echo $PATH"` to the `Compile Command` still gives `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

Why isn't Emacs using my ~/.bashrc for the compile command and is there another init file that it does use that is also used by normal bash shells?  What is different about the shell created by the `Compile Command`.

Comment: One option would be to add just the paths that you need, like this:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`

Comment: @lawlist Yes, but I'm looking to understand why it behaves this way and how to 'fix' it not work around it.

Comment: The library contained in this link will give you a start in the right direction to better understanding how to deal with the default behavior:  https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell  See also this link:  https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa1067/_index.html  (Basically apps launched from Finder inherit their environment from a .plist file rather than the shell environment.)

Comment: Well bash won't normally read your .bashrc and other init files unless you use the login switch (eg,`bash -l`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile` does not invoke `.bashrc` because [compilation uses a non-interactive shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Shell.html) and [`bash` invokes `.bashrc` when invoked as an *interactive* non-login shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Fortunately, `bash` does have a mechanism for initializing non-interactive shells via the environment variable `BASH_ENV`:

> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> `if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi`
>
> but the value of the
>   `PATH` variable is not used to search for the file name.

So if you set the `BASH_ENV` environment variable to `$HOME/.bashrc` it should invoke your `.bashrc` in the `compile` sub-shell.

Setting environment variables for OS X Mavericks applications seems to be a bit of an adventure in itself. I eventually resorted to putting it in my `.emacs` file, e.g.:

```
(setenv "BASH_ENV" "$HOME/.bashrc")
```

Answer (score 0):

My current work around is to do:

`Meta-x compile` `source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/myCode/src; make`

But, I'd still like to understand why `Meta-x compile` does not reflect the contents of `.bashrc`.